# Having issues while running ehopApp/PublicWeb application, throwing Badgateway exception

Tags: abp

I have pulled the EshopApp application and trying to run by following the documentation posted here:

https://github.com/abpframework/eShopOnAbp

Here everything is running perfectly only PublicWeb is having issues, everytime I am running it, throws Badgateway exception.

Please look into this and provide the solution?

[image]

I added this code , but not working :

```
  PreConfigure<AbpHttpClientBuilderOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ProxyClientBuildActions.Add((remoteServiceName, clientBuilder) =>
            {
                clientBuilder.AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(policyBuilder =>
                    policyBuilder.WaitAndRetryAsync(
                        3,
                        i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, i))
                    )
                );
            });
        });
```